# How to use a pipe with select after forking and executing?

Tags: c++, linux, select, pipe

I'm a noob to linux programming, so please bear with me. In my application, I fork(), then execl() another binary after having setup a single pipe for reading in. After the fork and exec are OK, i do a dup2() for reading in from the stdout of the executed binary. I need my parent application to wait for output from the process it has created and once there is output, read it. I figured I will use select(), and wait for a few milliseconds before trying to see if there is data to be read and if there is, use read(). However my code does not work because select() takes as argument an fd_set, while my pipe is of int converted by pipe() and dup2(). What can I do to overcome this and is there another alternative? Note, I'm not blocking the parent process until the process ends, but want to read info while the child process runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `select()` you must create a `struct fd_set` and populate it using the `FD_` macros.  In this way you will inform the function which descriptors you are interested in (note that it is common to be interested in several at once).  For example:

```
fd_set rfds;

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(your_input_fd, &rfds);

int retval = select(your_input_fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The first argument to select is to be the highest-numbered file descriptor you are interested in, plus one.  That, along with example code, is explained here:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set

Comment: That is what I read on linux.die.net, but it does not explain anywhere how or if I can use a pipe with select.
Do I have to somehow convert the pipe to an fd_set struct? Do I have to point to it? As I said, I already have an int foo, which is a pipe, which is duped with dup2. Can I use that with select, and if yes, how?

Comment: What you're calling a pipe is actually a file descriptor for the pipe.  Like John zwinck said, you need to add the file descriptor for the pipe to the fd_set.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out with your help Sean, thank you. It is just what you said. Declare an fd_set, use FD_ZERO and then FD_SET to add the pipe to the declared fd_set. Thank you!